# Will Aegis of the Gods negate my opponent's Erebos, God of the Dead for me?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am playing a life gain deck and I find that if an opponent plays [Erebos, God of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Erebos%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Dead) my deck is ruined because of its effect "your opponents can't gain life." If I run [Aegis of the Gods](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aegis%20of%20the%20Gods), whose effect is "You have hexproof", does that mean Erebos' ability is negated, or because it doesn't actually say "Target opponent can't gain life" Aegis' effect doesn't actually work?

Answer (score 6):

Aegis of the Gods will have no effect. You still won't be able to gain life, for the exact reason you suspect. From the definition of [Hexproof](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Hexproof):

> 702.11c "Hexproof" on a player means "You can't be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control."

Since Erebos' ability doesn't say 'target' anywhere, it doesn't target you, and Hexproof has no effect.

Alternately, you can find a way to remove Erebos from the battlefield. Exiling is one way. Erebos can't be destroyed, since Gods have *Indestructible.* Have you considered cars such as [Deicide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deicide) or [Banishing Light](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Banishing%20Light)?

Comment: Re: Deicide: Banishing Light also works and is a bit more versatile.

Comment: So in that case all i really need to do is exile it?

Comment: @srekcuf5 You need to remove it from the battlefield somehow. Exiling it is one way to do so.

Comment: Though note that it does help with [skullcrack](http://magiccards.info/query?q=Skull+crack&v=card&s=cname)

Comment: That it will, since it'll make Skullcrack get countered for its targets becoming invalid. But I don't think these comments should get too active with discussion. If only chat here were more active! (ง ͠° ͟ل͜ ͡°)ง